# Spiral Matrix in Anti-clockwise Direction

Tags: java, matrix, data-structures, spiral

I am trying to print the elements in the anti-clock direction in the spiral form.

but I am getting an element missing in the format.

eg:

1   2   3   4

5   6   7   8

9  10  11  12

13 14 15 16

starting from 4,
Instead of the actual output : 4 3 2 1 5 9 13 14 15 16 12 8 7 6 10 11

I am getting : 4 3 2 1 5 9 13 14 15 16 8 7 6 10 11

Also, can anyone give me an Optimized solution if you have

Here is my code:

```
public class Sprial_Matrix {
    
    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int m=4;
    int n=4;
    
    System.out.println("Elements: ");
    
    
    
    int arr[][] = new int[m][n];
    
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            arr[i][j]=s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    int k=0,l=0;
    
    while(k<m && l<n) {
    for(int i=n-1;i>=l;i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[k][i]+" ");
    }
    k++;
    
    for(int i=k;i<m;i++ ) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][l]+" ");
    }
l++;
    
    if(k<m) {
        for(int i=l;i<=m-1;i++)
        System.out.print(arr[m-1][i]+" ");
        }
        m--;
    
        }

    if(l<n) {
        for(int i=m-1;i>=l;i--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][n-1]+" ");
        }
        n--;
        
        }
    
    s.close();
}

}
```

Appreciate the feedback that you give and thanks,,,

Comment: It's not clear to me what the desired output is for the input.  Make certain each individual line is shown.

Comment: The desired output is as follows  : index 03,02,01,00, 10,20,30, 31,32,33, 23,13,  12,11, 21,22 .... I hope you understand this :)

Comment: I presume those are pairs of indices.  Your output does not look like a counter clockwise spiral.  To me it should be  `4 3 2 1 5 14 13 12 6 15 16 11 7 8 9  10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a poor formatting of your code. If you format the code with correct indents then you'll see that the last `if` statement is actually outside the `while` loop:

```java
  if(k<m) {
        for(int i=l;i<=m-1;i++)         // There is no { on this line!
        System.out.print(arr[m-1][i]+" ");
        }                               // So this } closes the 'if', not 'for'
        m--;
    
        }                               // And this } closes the 'while', not 'if'

    if(l<n) {                           // So this 'if' is outside the loop.
        for(int i=m-1;i>=l;i--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][n-1]+" ");
        }
        n--;
        
        }
```

Simple fix is to do the following:

```java
   if(k<m) {
        for(int i=l;i<=m-1;i++) {         // FIX: added {
        System.out.print(arr[m-1][i]+" ");
        }
        m--;
    
        }

    if(l<n) {
        for(int i=m-1;i>=l;i--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][n-1]+" ");
        }
        n--;
        
        }
   }                                   // FIX: added }
```

Better solution would be to use better formatting of the whole program. Also, your class has a typo in its name, Sprial, not Spiral.